# rails rendering actions twice for model with empty self-referential association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering, self-reference

I am pretty baffled by this one. I doubt anyone can tell me right off the bat what the issue is, but any answers suggesting ways of debugging and investigating this would be much appreciated -- I've tried putting in some debugging calls into the controller without much luck in following the path through the guts of Rails, so a pointer to where in the source to investigate would be great.

This occurs under both Ruby 1.8.7/Rails 2.3.5 and Ruby 1.9.2/Rails 3.0.1.

I have the following model:

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :collection_profile, :dependent => :destroy

  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Collection"
  has_many :children, :class_name => "Collection", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
end
```

with the following route:

```
resources :collections do
  resource  :collection_profile
  resources :collections
end
```

There's also some validation that ensures that these can't be nested more than one deep -- ie, a Collection can have a parent collection OR it can have children collections, not both.

If a Collection does not have children -- ie, either it is a subcollection or it is a standalone collection -- then any actions under that collection render twice. In other words:

Reloading show page once for a Collection with children:

```
Started GET "/collections/TheFirstCollection" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-11-09 20:55:07 -0500
...
Rendered collections/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1708.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1784ms (Views: 1706.0ms | ActiveRecord: 34.3ms)
```

Reloading show page once for a Collection without children:

```
Started GET "/collections/SecondCollection" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-11-09 20:56:48 -0500
...
Rendered collections/show.html.erb within layouts/application (637.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 921ms (Views: 654.6ms | ActiveRecord: 13.7ms)

Started GET "/collections/SecondCollection" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-11-09 20:56:55 -0500
...
Rendered collections/show.html.erb within layouts/application (828.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 906ms (Views: 843.8ms | ActiveRecord: 14.9ms)
```

The same thing happens for all the other nested resources (of which there are a bunch) -- eg /collections/[collection name]/profile, /collections/[collection name]/works, /collections/[collection name]/people -- if the collection has children, the actions all render once and return. Otherwise, they render twice.

Note -- the browser displays the results of the first render, but the browser status bar still shows "waiting" until the second render completes, but it does not redraw the screen, at least in Firefox or Safari.

I've created a test app with the same structure (using the same name "collection" for the model in case that was the source of the wonkiness), and the error doesn't duplicate.

Like I said above -- any ideas even how to debug this would be hugely appreciated.